# WaitHandle fundamental behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, waithandle

Have those two code blocks the same effect when looking at the console?
Please note: Currently I am still using and bound to .NET 3.5.

First:

```
for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Second:

```
class Worker
{
    static int i = 0;
    static ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);       
    static Object locky = new Object();
    static void Work(Object workItem)
    {
        WaitHandle[] wait = new [] { manualResetEvent };

        while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(wait))
        {
            lock (locky)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i++);
            }
        }
    }
}
// main:

Thread thread = new Thread(Worker.Work);
thread.Start();

for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    Worker.manualResetEvent.Set();
}
```

Will the waitHandle increase with every signal? Will the loop run until all signals are done?
Or will a signal be ignored when the thread is already working?

Can someone please bring some light into this?

Comment: The second code won't even compile, so no, they don't have the same effect. Once you've got code which will compile, I suggest you try it for yourself - if you can see a difference, there's obviously a significant difference. If you *can't*, then it's a more reasonable question (as it could be a subtle difference).

Comment: `ManualResetEvent`, as the name suggests, requires *manual resets*. It will be set until you `Reset` it - so you'll get an infinite cycle of writelines. Also, you cannot lock on value types! In any case, try to use the highest-level abstraction available. You're way too low for what you seem to know about multi-threading and synchronization - have a look at TPL, DataFlow and similar friendlier constructs instead.

Comment: @Luaan thank you exactly what I was missing.

Comment: corrected the lock of native type

Comment: Actually, if you want to go this way, you really need to learn much more. For example, `ManualResetEvent` (and `AutoResetEvent`) are not mutexes - more worker threads waiting for the event will get the same signal. And `ManualResetEvent.Set` is non-blocking - so you could end up in a situation where you've managed to call `Set` three times *before* the worker thread noticed even once. All in all, a `Semaphore` might be a lot more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: @Luaan will the Semaphore work like a stack or like a queue or without any special order?

Comment: It's just a counter, so there really isn't any notion of order :) I strongly recommend reading this at least - http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a `ManualResetEvent`, once you signal the event, it remains signaled until it's reset. Which means setting it once or three times will have the same effect.

This also means that the worker will go into an infinite loop because the event is never reset.

Also, you can't lock on value types. If you could, the int would be boxed and create a new `object` every time you lock on it - which means you'd be locking on a different object every single time, rendering the lock useless.

Comment: Fortunately, newer C# compilers explicitly forbid locking on a value type (unless it's manually boxed to an `object`) - the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Luaan Cool, I wasn't sure whether the compiler enforced this. I've updated my answer to state that "you can't do it" instead of "you shouldn't do it" :) Thanks

Comment: ... running endlessly until Worker.manualResetEvent.Reset() is called ... that has been my missing piece, exactly what I needed to know. Thanks